# I can't add two different function nodes

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, shader, nodes

I have two function nodes and I want to add them together. Both work well, but when I want to do something with them, an error occurs. This happens not only with adding.
[image: Example]
this is just an example.

I'm defining the Function via File. Both files are the same, except one returns red, and the second blue.
Code:

```
//UNITY_SHADER_NO_UPGRADE
#ifndef MYHLSLINCLUDE_INCLUDED
#define MYHLSLINCLUDE_INCLUDED


void Function1_float(out float4 Red) 
{
    Red = float4(1, 0, 0, 0);
}

#endif //MYHLSLINCLUDE_INCLUDED
```

I used this guide to create them:
[Unity Manual - Custom Function](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Custom-Function-Node.html)

Comment: Which Unity version are you on? I am on 2019.4.0f1 and have this problem too. I don't have any problem when switch to use string.

Comment: I'm using Unity 2019.3.0f6 Personal and also have no problems when using string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to change the name of the define "MYHLSLINCLUDE_INCLUDED" to be unique for each function. I think the intent was to only have your function declared once, but that could be colliding and preventing the other from loading.